# Restarting MariaDB Services on Swisscom Cloud

Tags: mariadb, swisscomdev

I have some issues connecting to the db since I have reached the `max_user_connections` limit, it would be possibile to restart the service or to reset all the connection from web console or cli?

Comment: please post details and code snippets about your DB code. Only you can stop and establish connections. How you do connection pooling? No one expect your app uses MariaDB connections. What's your database name?

Answer (score 1):

See `KILL CONNECTION` in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/kill.html